# Sql Parameter.Size and Output param

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Untill now I have never specified the parameters size when calling a procedure with parameters.
But suddenly one day i got an error:

> String[2]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

I have never seen that before, and it only accured in an output param.
So my question is when do I need to size a param, because it works fine as an input..

And, About Output and Output/Input. I have a parameter set as:

```
@HtmlImageType  VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT
```

But when I look at the table parameters It is classified as Input/Output, and in my C# code it only works with Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I look at the table parameters It is classified as Input/Output

That's because you do in fact send *in* a parameter that can be changed in the procedure and that value persisted to the caller, an *out* parameter.

> So my question is when do I need to size a param, because it works fine as an input

You need to size them at all times because the type is variable, `VARCHAR`. However, when providing a value as an `input` the size is inferred. As an `out` it can't infer that size and so the default is `0`.